# Is there a flutter plugin can show and highlight diff of two or more inputted texts

Tags: flutter

Is there any flutter plugin can show and highlight diff of two or more inputted texts like [this](https://www.w3docs.com/tools/code-diff/)

I found react has some [plguin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-diff-viewer) can do it, but i dont know if flutter can

Comment: May be this package help you: https://pub.dev/packages/fire_line_diff

Comment: this package can find the difference of two inputted texts, but how can i highlight them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.